How do I compare two docker images?
I have two Docker images, each with many layers. I want to compare all the files in teh first image to all the files in the second one, to see what's been changed.
I tried taring up the images using
docker image save <image no> > MyImage.tar

But when I untar this, I get 100+ directories, each holding
VERSION json layer.tar

So that's useless

You don't want docker image save; you want docker container export (which means you'll have to start a container from those images first).

A standard docker container image has layers.  These are co-ordinated via the manifest file.  This can save space; e.g. if two containers are built off the same base image then the server and runtime does not need to store that base twice.
It does, however, make it a PITA to work out what the result of all these layers are.
So what you can do, instead, is create the container from the image (this builds the run-view of the container, but doesn't start it) and then export it.
e.g.
% docker create --name bash bash
fe63a3c32ecc848faf586989ed57b61da5aa829a8e60b3856bd241dd14c09fcc

% docker export bash > bash.tar

% docker rm bash
bash

The resulting bash.tar is a literal view of the filesytem before the container starts running.

% tar tf bash.tar | head
.dockerenv
bin/
bin/arch
bin/ash
bin/base64
bin/bbconfig
bin/busybox
bin/cat
bin/chattr
bin/chgrp

